# How to retrieve a new Google id token on "Sign in with Google" flow?

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm using the Sign in With Google for Web flow.  I have sign in working using the google.accounts.id.initialize() method on the frontend.  I validate the token on the backend using the method described in [Verify the Google ID token on your server side](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token).

I use my own jwt token to validate on my apis, that expires in 15 minutes.  After the 15m I need to validate the user still has access to their google account.  Even if I was not using the jwt token, googles token has an `exp` claim of 1 hour.  They mention on that linked doc page that `client.verifyIdToken` validates this `exp` prop.

How do I get a new token from google or validate that the user is still valid, so I can regenerate a new jwt.  The only way I can see is by using `google.accounts.id.initialize({ callback: callback })`, where the callback returns the token.  But that is only called when the user signs in by clicking the google sign in button.  I can't request the user refresh the page and re-click the sign in button every 15 minutes. [Sign In With Google JavaScript API reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference) does not have any way to do this that I can see.

Comment: Your going to have to ask the user to authorize the application again after the token has expired